# Keras ,Tensorflow Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mnist

I already installed CUDA 8.0 and copied the cuDNN file in the directory as [Install CUDA (GPUs on Linux)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-install-cuda-gpus-on-linux) says.

I run mnist_cnn.py and got the following information:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3448] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
X_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
```

and finally

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_cnn.py", line 65, in <module>
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  File "/home/nsknsl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 308, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/nsknsl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 514, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/nsknsl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/nsknsl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 149, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/home/nsknsl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 90, in call
    x = K.in_train_phase(K.dropout(x, self.p, noise_shape), x)
  File "/home/nsknsl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1304, in in_train_phase
    x = tf.python.control_flow_ops.cond(tf.cast(_LEARNING_PHASE, 'bool'),
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python' has no attribute 'control_flow_ops'
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7ff2a70e4ba8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 532, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'TF_DeleteStatus'
```

so how can I load cuDNN DSO ?

Comment: I think that you have to add the directory that contains the `libcudnn.so` to your `DL_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, as described [on the same site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-linux-enable-gpu-support)

Comment: The website link has been changed to https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_linux

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, if you didn't yet, you need to run the following commands to set your environment variables:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

You can also add these commands to the end of your ~/.bashrc so they get executed next time you login.

From: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_linux#nvidia_requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, please make sure that you have already installed cudnn. The installation should be done separately after the installation of Cuda.
2. Then you need to find your path of 'libcudnn.so.' by:

   `sudo find /usr/ -name 'libcudnn.so'`

For me, I got `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib`.

3. You need also find your path where the libraries could be found by using the well-loaded library such as `libcufft.so`

   `sudo find /usr/ -name 'libcufft.so'`

   For me, I got `/usr/lib`.
4. Now copy the files to right place:

   `sudo cp /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcud* /usr/lib`
5. Quit the previous Tensorflow session and start a new one et
   to test. It works for me :)